# delete with webapi and angular-resource

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I'm trying to delete an item in my collection with angular-resource en asp.net webapi. The correct server side method is called, but there is no object sent with it: suitcase is null.

What am I missing in my code that takes care of sending the object?

the angular code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource']);

        myApp.config([
            '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state('suitcases.delete', {
                        url: '/suitcase/delete/:id',
                        controller: 'deleteSuitcaseController'
                    });
            }
        ]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('deleteSuitcaseController', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, Entry) {
            console.log('deleteSuitcaseController', $stateParams.id);

            $scope.deleteSuitcase = function () {
                var suitcase = Entry.get({ id: $stateParams.id });
                suitcase.$delete();
            };

            $scope.deleteSuitcase();
        });

angular.module('myApp').factory('Entry', function($resource) {

            return $resource(
                "api/suitcaseapi/:id", { id: '@@id' },
                { "update": { method: "PUT" } },
                { "add": { method: "POST" } }
            );
        });
```

the webapi code:

```
public class SuitcaseApiController : ApiController
    {
public void Delete(Suitcase suitcase)
        {
            Singleton.Instance.Suitcases.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == suitcase.Id);
        }
    }
```

If I change the server side method to the code below I get a 405 not allowed error in the browser.

```
    public void Delete(int suitcaseid)
        {
            Singleton.Instance.Suitcases.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == suitcaseid);
        }
    }
```

PS. I took out the code I think is irrelevant.

Comment: Entry is defined in the factory. See updated code example.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a delete, and as I can see you already have the suitcaseId, you don't need to call the API to return the entire object just to delete it. Just pass the Id along and the API take care of find the entity. Something like this:

**Angular controller/function**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('deleteSuitcaseController', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, Entry) {

    $scope.entity.id = $stateParams.id;

    $scope.deleteSuitcase = function () {

        $http.delete('/Suitcase/' + $scope.entity.id)
        .success(function (data, status, headers) {

        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        });
    }
});
```

**Delete Method API**

```
public void Delete(int id)
{   
    Singleton.Instance.Suitcases.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: this example isn't working since $http and $scope.entity is not defined. If I fix this I get a Method not allowed (405) error. This is btw the same error I get when I change the server side method in my example into public void Delete(int id). Besides all that, this solution is not using the resource library, may be I haven't been clear about that: my goal is using angular-resource for this.

Comment: Well I had only provided a sample of what the code might look. I don't know which libraries or resources you are using so I tried to create a generic code, just so you picture the idea. In your question you didn't specified you were getting 405 erros..